# Скорость работы apply в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, dataframe, group-by

Имеется dataframe из двух столбцов.
Группируя по первому, суммирую значения по втором. Делаю двумя способами

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].sum()
```

Скорость выполнения: 0,01 сек

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())
```

Скорость выполнения: 4,15 сек

Почему такая разница в скорости? 
Как ускорить работу, если нужна будет не просто сумма, а более сложная функция?
Например,

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(i) for i in x]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Series.apply()` и `DataFrame.apply(...)` - являются "не совсем векторизированными" функциями, которые чаще всего **значительно** медленнее своих векторизированных аналогов.

К сожалению, <s>серебрянной пули</s> универсального и быстрого решения не существует.

Так что подход обычно следующий:

1. если есть вектроизированная функция для решения нашей конкретной задачи, то используем ее
2. сравниваем скорость работы `.apply()` и обычного `list comprehension` и выбираем самый быстрый вариант. NOTE: при работе со строками (`object` dtype) `list comprehension` часто оказывается быстрее `.apply()` и иногда быстрее соответствующих векторизированных `Series.str.<method_name>` методов
3. если скорость не устраивает то пробуем один из [подходов, рекоммендованных разработчиками Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html):

   - Cython
   - Numba
   - pd.eval()